# Setting bufferCount value based on source observable

Tags: rxjs, observable

I have a scenario in which I have a stream of RxJS events that I pass to a custom operator. The events can be either

1. Single events, meaning they are complete when when it's received.
2. A partial event, meaning they are a part of a chunked larger event.

The events are of the type `CustomEvent` and `CustomChunkedEvent`, where the latter is built from the data of the first one.

```
interface ChunkedCustomEvent {
  id: string; // The id that chunks are grouped by
  index: number; 
  chunk: string; 
  chunkCount: number; // The number of chunks that make up the whole event
}
```

My custom operator groups the chunked events by the id, and then buffers the events with `bufferCount` until full, and then emits. This works great if the chunk count is the same as the current set buffer count, but I can't wrap my head around how I would set the `bufferCount` value to the `chunkCount` value so it's not constant but instead different for each chunk group.

At the moment, the operator looks like this, but it's obviously with a static number for the `bufferCount`.

```
export function handleChunkedEvents(): MonoTypeOperatorFunction<CustomEvent> {
  return pipe(
    groupBy(customEvent => {
      const chunkedEvent: ChunkedCustomEvent = { ...customEvent.data };
      return chunkedEvent.id;
    }),
    mergeMap(group => {
      return group.pipe(
        bufferCount(4), // I want this to be equal of the known chunk count
        map(groupOfChunked => {
          // Do something with the grouped chunks and return it as a whole
          // If it isn't a chunked event, return the event instead
        })
      )
    })
  );
}
```

Is there a way to achieve what I want or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Comment: _"If it isn't a chunked event, return the event instead"_ <- Are events of both types passing through this operator? Are there `CustomEvents` whose data property is something other than a `ChunkedCustomEvent`? More specifically, how do we tell whether an event is chunked or not? Check for `chunkCount` of 1, or something else...?

Comment: If the event isn't a chunked part of a larger whole, the `chunkedEvent.id` will be undefined, thus not grouped by anything. In that case, it should only buffer that event and emit immediately after. Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bufferCount` is just a convenient special case of `buffer`, which buffers
based on the emission of a "signal" observable. That's the way we want to go
here.

We're only dealing with the `mergeMap` below as it's all we need to change from
your example.

```js
mergeMap((group$) => {
  // Handle the non-chunked case - the group with a undefined key will emit
  // only non-chunked events - just let it do its thing
  if (!group$.key) return group$;

  // From the group, create a signal observable that fires when the chunkCount
  // matches the 0-index plus 1
  const chunkCountReached$ = group$.filter((event, i) => event.data.chunkCount === i + 1);

  return group$.pipe(
    buffer(chunkCountReached$),
    map((groupOfChunked) => {
      // Do something with the grouped chunks and return it as a whole
    })
  );
});
```

EDIT: This is also a valid solution, and has the benefit of completing the
group observable once `chunkCount` is reached.

```js
const chunkCountReached$ = group$.filter((event, i) => event.data.chunkCount === i + 1);

return group$.pipe(
  takeUntil(chunkCountReached$),
  toArray(),
  map((groupOfChunked) => {
    // Do something with the grouped chunks and return it as a whole
  })
);
```

FINAL EDIT (*because I can't help but codegolf*):

```js
return group$.pipe(
  takeWhile((event, i) => i + 1 < event.data.chunkCount, true),
  toArray(),
  map((groupOfChunked) => {
    // Do something with the grouped chunks and return it as a whole
  })
);
```

Comment: This looks promising, I'll have a look asap! :)

Comment: I ended up using the last edit of yours, simply great @backtick, thank you! Great learning opportunity for me. 

A small note, the `takeUntil` will exclude the first the first value that doesn't fulfill the `chunkCountReached$` condition, but the `takeWhile` works good since it has the `inclusive` value set to true!